# Select data from xml with python

Tags: python, xml

Does anyone know how i can select the data from this xml output.

`{'toplevel': {'CompleteSuggestion': [{'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao wikipedia'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao kaufen'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao koffein'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao turbo'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao kaufen schweiz'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao energy'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao original'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao rewe'}}, {'suggestion': {'@data': 'cola cao noir'}}]}}`

I need all data from suggestion.

THX

this is the code where i get data.

Comment: import requests
import xmltodict
url = "https://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=de&q=cola+cao"
response = requests.get(url)
data = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
print(data)

Comment: Please include that in your original post and not in the comments.  Also, that looks more like a Dictionary rather than XML.  Please also explain in detail what you mean by 'select data'.. what data?

Answer (score 2):

One of the options would be to [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get) the *data* while iterating over each `suggestion` level :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "https://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=de&q=cola+cao"

root = ET.fromstring(requests.get(url).content)

data = [sugg.get("data") for sugg in root.findall(".//suggestion")]
```

Alternatively, you can [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) by using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_xml(url, xpath=".//suggestion")["data"].tolist()
```

And if you really need to start from the dictionary made by [`xmldict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict), you can use :

```
data = [d["suggestion"].get("@data") for d in xmldict["toplevel"]["CompleteSuggestion"]]
```

Output :

```
print(data)

['cola cao',
 'cola cao wikipedia',
 'cola cao kaufen',
 'cola cao koffein',
 'cola cao turbo',
 'cola cao kaufen schweiz',
 'cola cao energy',
 'cola cao original',
 'cola cao rewe',
 'cola cao noir']
```